# Where does app_id in facebook's sharer.php come from?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am using facebooks's share button, exactly as specified in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/.
I tried the HTML5 and XFBML versions, but both generate the link below, which returns http error 500 when the user submits. If I manually remove the app_id parameter (which I did not inform anywhere), it works perfectly.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=309437425817038&sdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Fg1.globo.com%2Feconomia%2Fnoticia%2F2014%2F05%2Fministro-da-fazenda-diz-que-nao-vai-faltar-energia-no-pais.html&display=popup

I am using this from my company's intranet, to share a link from the company's external website.

This is my code:

```
   <!-- Facebook -->
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <fb:share-button href="<SHARED_URL>" type="button_count"></fb:share-button>
      <!-- <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<SHARED_URL>" data-type="button_count"></div>-->
```

So where does this app_id comes from? How do I get rid of it? I want to use the button with the share count, therefore I wouldn't like to call sharer.php directly.

Comment: I believe you have to register an APP with Facebook for the site you want to use the HTML5/XFBML (thus getting a unique ID for the app).

Comment: But only share dialog has an app_id param. Social plugins, which are the ones I want to use, don't. So facebook comes up with this id from my company's IP, since no matter what link I try to share, the same app_id is generated?

Comment: Looks like facebook developers fixed the problem. It works now...